# CSS hyphen throws error (invalid property value)

Tags: html, css, hyphenation

I want to break a text with hyphenation, but it brings an error:

[image]

> It says: "Invalid property value".

But in many docs they say, that the "auto" value exists!

It should break this text with hyphenation:

[image]

I hope, that someone can help me with that!

Comment: A related chrome bug [report](https://codereview.chromium.org/2342553003)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To add to their answers to check if you have the right browser at https://caniuse.com/#feat=css-hyphens

You can also check MDN's documentation about it and see how your language dictionary may not be supported yet.

(scroll to the bottom to see Hyphenation dictionary language compatibility)
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/hyphens

There is even a footnote that says for Chrome:

> No automatic hyphenation, only `-webkit-hyphens: none` is supported.

Comment: CSS Automatic Hyphenation for Windows/Linux/ChromeOS in `Chrome 88+` https://www.chromestatus.com/feature/5672891947417600

Answer (score 1):

If you take a look here http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-hyphens you can see that chrome doesn't really support hyphens.

"Only supported on Android & Mac platforms (and only the "auto" value) for now."

Answer (score 0):

Not all browsers support hyphens: auto which is under [CSS Text Module Level 3](https://drafts.csswg.org/css-text-3/)

For instance Chrome supports only inherit, initial, manual, none and unset with -Webkit- (13). What is the browser your are working with? Check CSS3 [browser support](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_browsersupport.asp) for more detail.

Answer (score 0):

'hyphens' is not supported by Chrome browser

Comment: This answer is no longer accurate. Other answers were more clear about the fact that it could be a temporary thing and linked to sites where one could find out the current status.