# Why doesnt hyphens: auto work in the chrome inspector?

Tags: css, sass, css-hyphens

I was editing my website and there is a really long word i had to use hyphens for.
I did some research and there is an option to use "auto" so I don't have to do it manually.
But when I edit it in my inspector it said "invalid property value"
I couldn't figure out why this happened.

[image]

Does anyone know where this is coming from? or does anyone have an explanation for it?

I tried every othore option and they all worked....
even w3schools says its an option 
https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_hyphens.asp

I know there is a alternative to use word-break but you dont get the "-" when you use that.

Comment: It's _"Only supported on [Android & Mac platforms (and only the "auto" value)](https://caniuse.com/#search=hyphens) for now." W3Schools should have been more clear about Chrome support.

Comment: Are you sure its not working only for chrome. Chrome supports hyphens. follow: https://caniuse.com/#search=hyphens. Maybe you have some empty characters while you copy-pasted the `hyphens: auto` in your editor. Try re-writing the value using the auto-suggestion.

Comment: @SudiptoRoy please read the exceptions to the Chrome support on caniuse.com. There's limitations to what platforms `hyphens` will work in Chrome.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why don't hyphens work for Chrome on Windows?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56174249/why-dont-hyphens-work-for-chrome-on-windows)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [CSS hyphen throws error (invalid property value)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46314381/css-hyphen-throws-error-invalid-property-value)

Comment: Hyphens: auto doesn't work on MacOs either in chrome, at least with my test case.  I tried hyphens: auto and "MyReallyLongWordThatShouldGetHyphenatedAndBroken".  Safari breaks it with hyphens as expected, chromes does not break it onto the next line at all.