# Why don't hyphens work for Chrome on Windows?

Tags: css, google-chrome

I have `hyphens` working on Android and Mac but it isn't showing up on PC. Both my PC and Mac are on: Chrome Version 74.0.3729.157 (Official Build) (64-bit)

The CSS is used on a website, in standard text-wrapping.

Does anyone know where I can find more information on why, and if it will be supported in the future?

```css
white-space: normal;
overflow-wrap: break-word;
word-wrap: break-word;
-ms-word-break: break-all;
word-break: break-word;
-ms-hyphens: auto;
-moz-hyphens: auto;
-webkit-hyphens: auto;
hyphens: auto;
```

Comment: https://caniuse.com/#search=hyphens and https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/hyphens

Comment: If you look at the caniuse link @j08691 provided, you'll see that only Mac and Android platforms are supported. And here's the ticket for the bug: https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=652964

Comment: @KyleUnderhill look at the "can i use" link provided above in the comments by j08691.  Chrome 74 has a footnote: "Only supported on Android & Mac platforms (and only the "auto" value) for now. See commit & related bug."

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Updated Answer: As of Chrome v88, this feature is available for use in Windows. Remember that you will need to have soft hyphens (`&shy;`) in your text where you want hyphens to appear based on container space.

---

Original Answer:

When Chrome shipped this feature, they did so [without support for Windows](https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromium/src/+/ed7e106e0e48b3afb160a5bdbb37649e307d2b05).

> Enable CSS hyphens property on stable
>
> This patch enables CSS hyphens property on stable.
>
> Following values are valid at this point:
>
> - **Android/Mac: manual | none | auto**
> - **Other platforms: manual | none**
>
> BUG=605840
>
> Review-Url: https://codereview.chromium.org/2342553003 
> Cr-Commit-Position: refs/heads/master@{#419461}

(emphasis mine)

As for when it will be available for use on Windows or other platforms, you can track that for yourself on the bug tracker: https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=652964

Note that Microsoft Edge only recently moved to a Chromium engine from its original EdgeHTML engine. Pre-Chromium versions of Edge still support hyphens just fine, just like Firefox. Newer versions of Edge, along with Chromium powered browsers like Chrome, Brave, Vivaldi, et al will suffer from this deficiency until it is implemented in Chromium.

In the future, I recommend checking for such support gotchas on the website https://caniuse.com - it usually has good information about feature support and any implementation details as footnotes (as it did in the case of `hyphens`).

Comment: I tried this in Chrome today but still no success. Works fine in Firefox. I use `hyphens: auto; text-overflow: ellipsis; overflow: hidden;` currently. So in Chrome you need to add &shy; to get this property supported?

Comment: @Bregt It seems so. Firefox may also have implemented the feature differently.